# SerializationException: Value has been serialized already

Tags: c#, serialization, exception

I implemented the ISerializable interface on my class so I serialize my datas as follows:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass: ISerializable
{
   public MyClass() {//default constructor}
   public int foo = 5;
   public GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   {
        info.AddValue("foo",foo,typeof(int));
   }
}
```

This compiles whitout errors. But then I decide that I want to add an `float` member to `MyClass` class, so now my definition for `MyClass` is :

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass: ISerializable
{
   public MyClass() {//default constructor}
   public int foo = 5;
   public float ffoo = 3.14;   //the added member
   public GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   {
        info.AddValue("foo",foo,typeof(int)); 
        info.AddValue("ffoo",ffoo,typeof(float));
   }
}
```

But now the `SerializationException` is thrown saying that the value (`foo`) variable was already serialized. So how can I avoid this behavior? Because I am sure that later on I will add more members to my class which need to be serialized.

Comment: Where is the exception thrown?

Comment: The error is thron at the line 
`info.AddValue("foo", foo, typeof(int)); `
I think that this is because I've already serialized this value before

Comment: You are not pasting your source code there. The code above will not compile, it has multiple problems, first, the default constructor comments out the closing bracket, and second, the GetObjectData method is missing the return type (void actually). If you want your problem to be resolved, please give us the correct information. Otherwise, you always have the option to close the question.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jjg4qD.  Suggest editing your question to create a proper [minimal, complete, and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code sample that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the constructor is called for deserialization, and the info already contains the member foo.

In that constructor, you should read from info your field values. ISerializable has another method (GetObjectData) for serialization and you should add your fields to the info in the body of that method, not in the constructor.

Comment: Sorry for this, I just wrote it wrongly. In my actual code I do this inside the GetObjectData method, but I have this problem.

Comment: Can you please paste the final version of your code?

Comment: But from the exception message you get, I am sure that you were adding to info while italready contained the "foo"

Comment: Plase, also add the serialization constructor. I am not able to reproduce the error with this much. There must be something wrong with the rest of the source code

Comment: This is just an ideea. That s not my code. Errors like comment the closing bracket just ignore dem. As you suspected my problem is that i want to serialize values that i've already serialized. God damn

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/dj47jofmd/
Ok so this is my full code  . Now let's say I run it for the first time. That'll be ok(it'll compile without any errors). But let's say I want to add a new member(somewhere at line 9 for example), and I want to serialize this new member too ,inside the GetObjectData method. Now when I will run this code an error will be thrown at line 13(because that value was already serialized). So how can I avoid this(e.g. How can I serialize values that I've already seriialized before).And sorry for these late responses, I've been busy.

Comment: An what is the exception? I mean, what is the serialization exception say instead of foo? ("foo" has already serialized. What is the actual key name instead of "foo"?)

Comment: The exception is the title of this thread. SerializationException: Value has been serialized already

Comment: Ok but on which line it throws this exception? It is important for me to know.

Comment: This code will throw an error everytime I try to serialize a value that was serialized before. But the first time this error is thrown is at line 13.

Comment: Can you please share the code where you serialize the instance of  ParticularRound object? With each serialization, a new SerializationInfo object is created, it should not throw any exceptions with repeated serializations, unless you invoke GetObjectData yourself.

Comment: The GetObjectData method is meant to be invoked by the serialization libraries, not by yourself.

Comment: No I'm not. I just let the Serialize() function of the BinnaryFormatter class to do this.